# Asp.Net View Rendering unexpected output

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Why does this code work perfectly, outputting the HTML as expected and...

```
<div class="page home-page custom-container d-flex flex-column">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("PersonalizedProducts")
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("RecommendedProducts")
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("SuggestedProducts")
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("HomePageProducts")
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("HomePageNewProducts")
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("CategoryFeaturedProducts")
</div>
```

...this one doesn't work:

```
<div class="page home-page custom-container d-flex flex-column">
@{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    tasks.Add(Component.InvokeAsync("PersonalizedProducts"));
    tasks.Add(Component.InvokeAsync("RecommendedProducts"));
    tasks.Add(Component.InvokeAsync("SuggestedProducts"));
    tasks.Add(Component.InvokeAsync("HomePageProducts"));
    tasks.Add(Component.InvokeAsync("HomePageNewProducts"));
    tasks.Add(Component.InvokeAsync("CategoryFeaturedProducts"));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
</div>
```

The components mentioned above are 100% independent between themselves and do not share anything but a database, which they do no alter since these are fetch-only components...

Comment: whats the error you are getting? can you post that

Comment: There is no actual error, the page just comes back blank...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting html output then you will need to add more code to output the html:

```
<div class="page home-page custom-container d-flex flex-column">
@{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    tasks.Add(Component.InvokeAsync("PersonalizedProducts"));
    tasks.Add(Component.InvokeAsync("RecommendedProducts"));
    tasks.Add(Component.InvokeAsync("SuggestedProducts"));
    tasks.Add(Component.InvokeAsync("HomePageProducts"));
    tasks.Add(Component.InvokeAsync("HomePageNewProducts"));
    tasks.Add(Component.InvokeAsync("CategoryFeaturedProducts"));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    foreach( var t in tasks)
    {
        var var1 = await t;
        @var1;
    }
}
</div>
```

Comment: Almost! the secret was to declare `List<Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent>>`!